# Construction of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> 本当に来てくれたんだね。へー、こういうのもアリなんだ。個別の相談事なんてのもさ。

I think I understand the global meaning of the sentence, but I don't understand how the sentence has been made.

I assume that by 個別の相談事なんてのもさ。it means that he wishes to have a different discussion, but I can't say more than that.

個別の相談 => A different (special) discussion

事 => I have no idea what this one means in this case

なんて => I assume it is the one showing something like surprise

のも。I'm not sure at all, is it an emphasis to say "Especially since it is a different discussion, (I'm surprised) that you really came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if it's an actual abbreviation thereof, but I believe なんての as a set casual expression is equivalent to などというの, and essentially means "something like", "the likes of", etc.

相談 and 事 aren't really separate words here; 相談事{そうだんごと} is something of a set expression that means roughly the same as 相談 on its own; I'd say the difference is just that 相談事 sounds a little more concrete, like it's about a specific topic or a more formalised discussion.

個別 doesn't really mean "different" or "special" here but rather "individual" - he's specifying 個別の相談事 "an individual, one-on-one discussion" as opposed to a discussion involving everyone.

And finally the のも - this is linking back to the のも in the previous sentence. This whole final clause is a clarification of what he means by こういうの in the previous sentence, so it's possible to rephrase them as a single sentence　へー、個別の相談事なんてのもアリなんだ "Wow, so individual consultations like this are allowed too, are they?"

Separately, the two sentences could be translated as "Wow, so stuff like this is allowed too, is it? You know, things like individual consultations." (The explanatory さ particle in this instance fulfils a similar role to the "you know" in the English sentence, helping to mark the final clause as a clarification of the preceding one.)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. If my understanding is correct, the second のも is linked with the first one, isn't it ? But then, why is it こういう"のも" in the first place ? Would it be correct to say こういうはアリなんだ。? If so, what would be the nuance between them ?

Comment: こういうは doesn't make any sense, because a verb can't be the topic, it needs の to nominalise it first. こういうのはアリなんだ would make sense, but it would just mean "so stuff like this is OK", losing the sense of "so *even* stuff like this is OK".